# Add 'last updated' timestamp to Orchard CMS website

Tags: orchardcms

How do I add a last updated timestamp to the footer of my Orchard website? That is, the date when a change was made to the content via the CMS admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to add it, it's already there on the Common part, it's the published date if you want the date of the latest publication of the item, or the modified date if you really want the last time the item had any modification. Add this to a template override for the common part (parts.common.metadata.cshtml): `@Model.ContentPart.PublishedUtc` or `@Model.ContentPart.ModifiedUtc`

Comment: Great thanks, however this puts the modified date of each part on all content parts, so I have 10 different dates on the page now - do you know how I could get the last modified date of the whole website and show it once in the footer?

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted. The last modified date of the whole web site? That's an unusual request, you'll have to make a custom query for that, using content manager.

Comment: Now that you mention it modified date for each page does sound better. Thanks for putting me on the right path.